# SQL. Deleting data from a table, but maintaining the relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work in PostgreSQL

I have two tables. The first is the product and the second is the receipt. They are referenced using a foreign key (the product in the receipt table). I need to delete the product row from the product table, but to keep the reference. I wanted to make it a "virtual table" (product) where the receipt table will reference after deleting information from the main product table.

But I can't figure out how to do it... Can someone tell me or show me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a foreign key relationship to a non-existent row.  So, do a soft-delete.  That is, add a column to the `products` table such as `is_deleted`.

Then don't actually delete the row.  Just set the column to `true`.

It can be helpful to have a view for active products:

```
create view v_products as
    select p.*
    from products p
    where not is_deleted;
```

EDIT:

If you want to change the row in the original table, you can use a `cascading` option on the trigger.  Use `on delete cascade` to remove the row in `receipts` or `on delete set null` to set the referencing value to `NULL`.  I'm not a fan of these because you lose the original data.

Comment: It's a pity that the trigger can't change the reference to the virtual table after deleting a row  from the main table.  I will think. I agree that we will be much easier with the column

Comment: @JuniorLittle . . . If you want to `NULL` out the value you can use a cascading constraint.  I'm not a fan of changing the data.